# Meaning of: "I kinda hit it and quit it and left ya'll hanging"

Tags: translation, contractions, lyrics, offensive-language

Today, while I was listening to a song ([Fort Minor - Welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REAwGmv0Fuk)), I heard the following sentence:

> *I kinda hit it and quit it and left ya'll hanging*

One of the meanings I found w/ Google translator:

> *Golpear un poco y lo pararon e izquierda le cuelga*.

I don't know if that's the correct meaning.

Comment: Can you give us a rough translation of your non-English sentence? I'm guessing it's Spanish but It's difficult to tell you whether that translation is correct since most of us don't speak Spanish and translating to another language really isn't what we do.

Comment: The rapper is apologizing for appearing dilettantish.

Comment: For me, it looks a bit like it's about the history of the project (Fort Minor) itself. According to its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Minor), a song in the project made it to "No. 4 on the Billboard Hot 100 chart" *("kinda hit it")*, and that was in the period between 2004-2006, then the project went on hiatus *("quit it")* for almost a decade *("left ya'll hanging")*, before returning in 2015. This is just my impression anyway, and lyrics are open to anyone's interpretation, which is why it's usually considered off-topic here on ELL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about judging the accuracy of a translation into a language other than English.

Answer (score 2):

The phrases he uses are heavily idiomatic and are not likely to be translated well by an automatic service.

**Hit it and quit it** is slang that means something like ["To have a sexual encounter for physical gratification, and part company with the other partner immediately thereafter."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_it_and_quit_it)  That is probably not what the singer literally means, given the context of the rest of the lyrics; he's probably using it in a more general metaphorical sense of "I did something, then did not follow up on it."

**To leave someone hanging** means [to leave them waiting for the finish or continuation of something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+hanging).

So Damkerng's assessment is pretty much on-target: Fort Minor is apologizing for having done something but then not followed up on it, thereby having left the listeners waiting for more.